# LinearLayout cannot be cast to DrawerLayout

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to add an image on top of the navigation drawer but every time I run it the application crash; the logcat gives me this error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams`

Here is what I'm trying to do:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private Menu mymenu;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0]));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1]));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2]));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3]));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4]));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5]));

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(1);
        }

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
    }

    /***
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        //boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        //menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

     /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new PoliticaFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new GiustiziaFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new MediaFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new EconomiaFragment();
            break;     
        default:
            break;
        }

        /*if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }*/

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = frgManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Add our menu
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        // We should save our menu so we can use it to reset our updater.
        mymenu = menu;

        //
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
        // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
          return true;
        }
        // Handle your other action bar items...

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

      <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/drawer"
       android:layout_width="240dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_gravity="start" >

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/image_view"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@drawable/logo_il_fatto_quotidiano" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**NavDrawerItem.java**

```
public class NavDrawerItem {
    private String title;

    public NavDrawerItem(){}

    public NavDrawerItem(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return this.title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

**NavDrawerListAdapter.java**

```
public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

    public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems){
        this.context = context;
        this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return navDrawerItems.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {       
        return navDrawerItems.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**string.xml**

```
    <!-- Nav Drawer Menu Items -->
    <string-array name="nav_drawer_items">
        <item>Item 1</item>
        <item>Item 2</item>
        <item>Item 3</item>
        <item>Item 4/item>
        <item>Item 5</item>
        <item>Item 6</item>
    </string-array>
```

Do you know where am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: After a quick glance it doesn't look like anything is wrong with your code, so I would try cleaning the project (in Eclipse, Project > Clean) to refresh it and then try again

Comment: I've already tried to clean the project several times but the result remain the same

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter instead of:

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
```

try

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent, false);
```

Otherwise the layout params of the inflated view will be that of whatever is defined in the row xml. This probably does not match the base containers. By passing the ViewGroup that the view will be added too, the LayoutInflater can create the correct type of LayoutParams to match the hierarchy. The false passed in at the end is to make sure the LayoutInflater just creates the view but does not attach it to the parent via addView (this is required inside an adapter since AdapterView does not implement addView())

Comment: I've tried your alternative but the result is the same. Anyway I haven't fully understood in the second section of your answer..